# Add extra 100 percent margin left to each child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching but haven't been able to find anything. I need to position a bunch of 100% width child elements inside of a 100% width container.

Each child element needs to be positioned + 100% margin-left more than the previous child.
Basically simulate how they would be if they were just positioned with float left

This is telling all children after the first child to move right 100%

```
$('.responsiveSlider').find('.responsiveSliderSlide').each(function() {
    $(this).next().css('margin-left', +100+'%');
});
```

right now I'm getting
child 1 margin-left 0
child 1 margin-left 100%
child 1 margin-left 100%
child 1 margin-left 100%

trying to achieve:
child 1 margin-left 0
child 1 margin-left 100%
child 1 margin-left 200%
child 1 margin-left 300%

---SOLUTION---

```
var thisSlideWidth = 1;
$('.responsiveSlider').find('.responsiveSliderSlide').each(function() {
    //var thisSlideWidth = $(this).width();
    var nextSlideLocation = thisSlideWidth + '00%';
    $(this).next().css('margin-left', nextSlideLocation);
    thisSlideWidth++;
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out... updated original post with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me it looks like you used

```
    $(#myItem).css("margin-left", "+100%")
```

in your jquery statement instead of

```
    $(#myItem).css("margin-left", "+=100%")
```

€dit: nvm, i referred to the original text without code

Comment: It's not that it wasn't moving the content over, the problem was it was moving all subsequent elements to the same position. OP has solution... probably a much better way to do it though haha